# Meaning of "slice" in the context of mutual exclusion problems

Tags: concurrency, operating-system, mutual-exclusion

What does "slice" mean in the following statement:

```
p0 tests lock (now, slice before actually setting lock)
```

The author is trying to show mutex is not met for this program.
It's from http://www.mcs.csueastbay.edu/~billard/os/mutex.txt

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From context, I believe it means to context switch (i.e. that there is a *timeslice* boundary at the current point). Thus,

```
p0 tests lock (now, slice before actually setting lock)
p1 tests lock (this makes p1 think it is still available)
```

means

```
p0 tests lock
timeslice ends -- context switch to p1
p1 tests lock
...
```